# Get the value of a variable to fire an event

Tags: jquery, var

I'm trying to do a very simple thing, I just want the `.text` div to appear when the `number` value gets to `1000`.

Here's the full code I'm using

```js
                $(window).scroll(function(){ 
                var number = Math.round($(document).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 1000);
                $(".head").text(number + ' lieues');
                    if  (number == 1000){
                    $('.text').addClass('show')};
                });
```

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
}
.head{
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 10%;
  font-family: 'insitu_light'; 
  font-size: 30px;
}
.show{display: block !imporant;}
.text{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'insitu_light'; 
  font-size: 30px;
}
.footer{
  height: 10%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'insitu_light'; 
  font-size: 30px;  
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="description" content="Mille Lieues">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">

 <title>Mille Lieues</title>
 </head>
  <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="head">0 lieues</div>   
            <div class="text">
            Quoi de plus fédérateur qu’une piscine pour incarner le brassage, la rencontre, les jeux et la fête? Pensé comme un outil au service du vivre-ensemble, de la cohésion et de l’innovation sociale, le projet d’un lieu de vie hybride, ouvert au plus grand nombre, est aussi la promesse d’une stimulation nouvelle dans un territoire aux mille visages. Ville ouverte, ville-monde, ville de rencontres et de surprises, le territoire dionysien est, tel un kaléidoscope, riche de ses identités plurielles. Rouvrir ce site iconique au public, c’est d’abord proposer aux Dionysiens et à leurs visiteurs de se le réapproprier et de participer à l’expérience de l’investir pour en faire émerger de nouveaux usages. Le projet Grand Bassin consiste à fédérer des acteurs venus d’horizons divers pour que les barrières économiques et symboliques tombent, et que réapparaisse un vivre-ensemble. Abolir ces frontières, c’est donner un cadre à la diversité et à la transdisciplinarité: ateliers, expositions, concerts, spectacles et performances rythmeront la vie de ce nouvel espace. La résidence du Grand Bassin, entre hôtel, gîte et auberge de jeunesse, offrira même la possibilité d’y dormir. Accueillir et relayer les initiatives entrepreneuriales, culturelles, artistiques, sportives et citoyennes en ce lieu singulier, c’est le défi que se sont lancé Cultplace et La Bellevilloise, avec le savoir-faire des architectes de Jung Architectures et d’Encore Heureux.»
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason this doesn't work, Do you have any clue ? 
Thanks !

Comment: what do you have inside `show` class? post your html and css

Comment: A simple `display:block;`

Comment: Guys! it works fine.. Your code has no problem https://jsfiddle.net/dvxy0fa0/

Comment: Yep my bad, a simple `display:block !important;` made it work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery hide and show function i have edited your code.

```js
                $(window).scroll(function(){ 
                var number = Math.round($(document).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 1000);
                $(".head").text(number + ' lieues');
       
                    if  (number == "1000"){
                    $('.text').show()
                    }else{
                    $('.text').hide()
                    };
                });
```

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0;
}

#container {
}
.head{
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 10%;
  font-family: 'insitu_light'; 
  font-size: 30px;
}
.show{display: block !imporant;}
.text{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'insitu_light'; 
  font-size: 30px;
}
.footer{
  height: 10%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'insitu_light'; 
  font-size: 30px;  
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="description" content="Mille Lieues">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">

 <title>Mille Lieues</title>
 </head>
  <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="head">0 lieues</div>   
            <div class="text">
            Quoi de plus fédérateur qu’une piscine pour incarner le brassage, la rencontre, les jeux et la fête? Pensé comme un outil au service du vivre-ensemble, de la cohésion et de l’innovation sociale, le projet d’un lieu de vie hybride, ouvert au plus grand nombre, est aussi la promesse d’une stimulation nouvelle dans un territoire aux mille visages. Ville ouverte, ville-monde, ville de rencontres et de surprises, le territoire dionysien est, tel un kaléidoscope, riche de ses identités plurielles. Rouvrir ce site iconique au public, c’est d’abord proposer aux Dionysiens et à leurs visiteurs de se le réapproprier et de participer à l’expérience de l’investir pour en faire émerger de nouveaux usages. Le projet Grand Bassin consiste à fédérer des acteurs venus d’horizons divers pour que les barrières économiques et symboliques tombent, et que réapparaisse un vivre-ensemble. Abolir ces frontières, c’est donner un cadre à la diversité et à la transdisciplinarité: ateliers, expositions, concerts, spectacles et performances rythmeront la vie de ce nouvel espace. La résidence du Grand Bassin, entre hôtel, gîte et auberge de jeunesse, offrira même la possibilité d’y dormir. Accueillir et relayer les initiatives entrepreneuriales, culturelles, artistiques, sportives et citoyennes en ce lieu singulier, c’est le défi que se sont lancé Cultplace et La Bellevilloise, avec le savoir-faire des architectes de Jung Architectures et d’Encore Heureux.»
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go for `>=` than `==` in your Code. Also check if the number reaches 1000.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
  var number = Math.round($(document).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height()) * 1000);
  console.log()
  $(".head").text(number + ' lieues');
  if  (number >= 1000){
    $('.text').addClass('show')
  }
});
```